# Dragging selected text into an input does not fire "DOMNodeRemoved"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When I drag & drop text from div to input not fire `DOMNodeRemoved` event. How verify text has been deleted?

js:

```
$(function() {
  $('.content').on('DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  });
});
```

html:

```
<h2>Div content editable</h2>
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  drop text to input
</div>
<h2>Input</h2>
<input class="input" type="text"/>
```

demo: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/izorij/1/edit)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here, but deleting text has nothing to do with removing a DOM element. A DOM node will only be removed by the `removeChild()` native method.

Comment: The event is fired when you add/ remove DOMNote in your specific listening area. (`.content`). Not when you change a TextNote

Comment: Copying text and pasting it in a text field has nothing to do with `DOMNodeRemoved`.

Comment: @NULL is right... However in some cases DOM automatically creates `textNode`s, removing text still doesn't remove any nodes.

Comment: @NULL when I d'n'd text between 2 div DOMNodeRemoved event trigger. What's the difference?

Comment: @Marcell Fulop I have model with a few fields. These fields are presented on the page as 'div[contenteditable="true"]'. I need to catch and record the change in the model.

Comment: @Georgeek The Node gets removed from one div and appended to another?

Comment: @NULL no... I was wrong. So I found solution - use "input" event.

Comment: @Georgeek or `keyup`, `blur`, `focusout`, `keydown`, etc....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is what you are looking for:

http://jsbin.com/izorij/5/edit

```
var cached;
$(function() {
  $('.content').on('focusout', function(event) {
    if(cached!=this.innerHTML) {
      console.log(event);
      cached = this.innerHTML;
    }
  });
});
```